# Unable to move files to my SD card - how can I do this?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, files

I have tried moving files from the Android (internal) storage (now almost full) to the 16G unused SD card I have installed.  I click and hold the item I want to move (i.e. a movie file) and the option to move (cut) is offered.  I press it and see the flag 'holdingFILENAME.wmv'.

I navigate to the area I want to move it to and press the icon (like a paper icon) in the top right of my screen.  I have the option to move, attach, copy, or delete.  I select move, but nothing happens. Any ideas how I can move files?

I am using Android v4.0.3, kernel 3.0.8+, baseband 1.01.

Comment: What file browser are you using?

Comment: embarassed to say im not sure... came w tablet.  icon is yellow folder w android logo on cover.  text:file manager below icon

Comment: default file managers have always been finicky in my opinion. check out the options below :)

Comment: tks for help so far btw... have installed astro but it doesnt seem to find my external 16g sd card...  only the mounted (internal) one... :(  ideas?

Comment: same for x-plore......  ok, this must be something stupid im doing.  on my tablet settings i see the  'internal storage' which seems to refer to mnt/sdcard.  then there is the 'extsd' which nothng seems to be able to either see or copy to.  my original file manager sees it but wont copy to it.  these other applications seem unable to recognise it.... help???

Comment: ok u lovely people...  i found the extsd!!  YaY!  however i just tried to copy something and i cant. get the error: libcore.io.ErnoException:open failed:EACCESS (permission denied)....  Doh!??????

Comment: it sounds like you're trying to do something that requires root... what is the filepath of the file you're trying to copy?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what device are you using? The Motorola Xoom was originally set up so that the external SD card was mounted read only (I'm not sure if they ever changed this, either). It's possible you're in a similar situation.

Comment: @eldarerathis the (non-US) Xoom sorted this out in the 3.1 update, not sure if/when it was sorted in the US firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Astro or if possible (I mean if you are rooted) Root Explorer.
In case "move" fails, then try "copy" first and after successful copy revert to the original location and delete the aforementioned file.
You're done!

Answer (score 1):

I would use [X-plore File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore&hl=en). It has a split-view and you can simply open the location you wish to copy *from* on one side, and the location you wish to copy *to* on the other side, and **long-press** and choose **move** from the menu. The move location will be the location you have open in the other pane by default.